# Rule-based labeling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule-based

I'm trying to label visited countries in a world map shapefile, what is wrong with my rule :

`if( "Visited" = 'yes', "NAME", NULL)`

[image]

Comment: Your rule is valid, are all the 'yes' values lower case or is there a mixture?

Comment: all are lower case

Comment: Can you  post a screen of your label configuration and attributes windows ? Maybe we will see something not right.

Comment: What is the issue that you are experiencing?

Comment: Screen posted sorry it's french

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your formula goes to "label with" ... not in the "filter" field ...

[image: Labelling]

Comment: it seems like it, so can you explain what filter is used for? please

Comment: Yes ! That's the reason :) Good shot ! I added a screenshot to your answer. @Nordinator, he's got it right you should change the V tick to his answer

Comment: perfect, clean, straight to the point

Comment: Your initial formula already contains a 'filtering' condition so u're able to leave the **filter** field blank (if u want ...)

Answer (score 8):

As alternate solution, instead of using rule-based labelling,  you can put your formula in the normal labelling field like below.

[image: labelling]

Comment: Avec plaisir ;) Don't forget to click the upper arrow also in front of my post if it helped you :)