# Labeling selected items out of a column in an attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, attribute-table

I have a layer of roads from [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/31.9748/34.9547).
I have selected 166 "Motorway or highway" road type out of 3,986 rows.
[image]
I need to label only this road type without deleting any data.
When I am typing  "TYPE" in the "Label with" window I have all the road types labeled.[image]
How can I label only this selected rows?

Comment: It quite similar to this question : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251638/rule-based-labeling-in-qgis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can achieve this with more flexibility by using rule-based labeling.  Instead of "show labels for this layers" choose "rule-based labeling, add a new rule (plus button).
[image]

In the filter box type `"TYPE"='Motorway or highway'`

and choose "TYPE" for the label with input.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want a row's NAME displayed only when that row's TYPE is 'Motorway or highway'.  If that is the case then you can use the following in the "Label with" field (instead of the string `TYPE` that you currently have):

```
if (TYPE='Motorway or highway', NAME, '')
```