# Showing labels just for a specific point type

Tags: qgis, point

If I have a bunch of points all on the same layer and they are all categorised by different types in the Attribute Table, is there an easy way to just show labels for one type and not the others? Maybe through an expression?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rule-based labeling in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251638/rule-based-labeling-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

`if("category column" LIKE 'category of interest',"label column",'')`

Set this as the expression to label by, after you replaced `"category column"` with the column you did you classification on, `'category of interest'` with what you want to be labeled (keep the `'` if it's a string, otherwise omit them), and `"label column"` with the column or value you want the points to be labeled with.